# asyncio.Queue - put urls from txt file

Tags: python, asynchronous, queue, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I need to pass URLs from txt file to the script that fetch URLs and do some work with the help of `aiohttp` and `asyncio`. So I use `asyncio.Queue` to put URLs from txt file into queue. The nuance is that the  txt file may be very large and may not fit in memory, and I tried to use queue `maxsize`. But when the limit is less than number of URLs - script is stuck. So I have 2 questions:

1. where is my mistake?
2. maybe there is better solution than using `asyncio.Queue` for this case?

**script.py:**

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def fetch(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


async def main():
    with open("urls.txt", 'r') as f:
        queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=5)
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            await queue.put(line)
        # await queue.join() - tried this

    while not queue.empty():
        current_url = await queue.get()
        try:
            content = await fetch(current_url)
            print(f"{current_url}: {content[:15]}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error fetching {current_url}: {e}")
        finally:
            queue.task_done()

asyncio.run(main())
```

**urls.txt:**

```
https://www.google.com/
https://www.youtube.com/
https://www.facebook.com/
https://www.wikipedia.org/
https://www.amazon.com/
https://www.instagram.com/
https://www.twitter.com/
https://www.tumblr.com/
https://www.pinterest.com/
https://www.reddit.com/
```

In this script I use `maxsize=5` and number of URLs in txt file is 10. I have tried to add `await queue.join()` after `for line in f:` loop but it didn't help. Script works only without `await queue.join()` and when `maxsize` >= number of URLs or is not specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program structure is wrong. To use a Queue you need a consumer (one or more) that reads from the queue in parallel.

Here is an simple example how you can create 3 workers that donwload the content as you put the URLs into the Queue. At the end we end the workers by putting `None` to the queue:

```py
import asyncio

from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def fetch(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        current_url = await queue.get()
        try:
            if current_url is None:
                break

            content = await fetch(current_url)
            print(f"{current_url}: {content[:15].strip()}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error fetching {current_url}: {e}")
        finally:
            queue.task_done()


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=5)

    # for example, we create 3 workers consuming the queue
    workers = {asyncio.Task(consumer(queue)) for _ in range(3)}

    with open("urls.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            await queue.put(line)

    # end the workers
    for _ in range(len(workers)):
        await queue.put(None)

    await queue.join()


asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
https://www.google.com/: <!doctype html>
https://www.facebook.com/: <!DOCTYPE html>
https://www.wikipedia.org/: <!DOCTYPE html>
https://www.amazon.com/: <!doctype html>
https://www.instagram.com/: <!DOCTYPE html>
https://www.tumblr.com/: <!doctype html
https://www.youtube.com/: <!DOCTYPE html>
https://www.twitter.com/: <!DOCTYPE html>
https://www.pinterest.com/: <!DOCTYPE html>
https://www.reddit.com/: <!DOCTYPE
```

Comment: Thank you! And is it good practice to use `Queue` with explicit `maxsize` to deal with large files?

Comment: @zaelcovsky It all depends on your use case. If you have lots of RAM you can have bigger maxsize (or unlimited). It also depends how fast your workers are reading from the queue etc.